# Trying to copy certain rows of data that match criteria to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel and I am attempting to transfer data that matches criteria (a code) to another Sheet.

**The Error itself occurs on the line**

```
a = Worksheets("ToExtract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

where I get a

> run-time error 9.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    a = Worksheets("ToExtract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a

        If Worksheets("ToExtract").Cells(i, 3).Value = "20040155" Then

            Worksheets("ToExtract").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("ToExtract").Activate

        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ToExtract").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What value is Rows.Count?

Comment: qualify the `Rows.Count` to an explicit worksheet and it will work. For example: `Worksheets("ToExtract").Cells(Worksheets("ToExtract").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: a = Worksheets("ToExtract").Cells(Worksheets("ToExtract").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row .  You will need to do the same thing for *b*.

Comment: @dbmitch Rows.Count was equal to 1048576

Comment: @Cyril I tried this but the same error is still occuring

Comment: What value are you trying to get - if it's the last row - 1 - why not just do the calc instead of this convoluted method? `a = Worksheets("ToExtract").Rows.Count -1`

Comment: Are you sure your worksheet is named "ToExtract"? If the sheet name doesn't exist, Excel would indeed display run-time error 9. Make sure the spelling is exactly right.

Comment: @dbmitch I just started this and I am sure there is a more effective and efficient method, I just don't know how to copy certain data into a new sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I edited your code.
It's work fine for me :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Declare your workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'Declare all your worksheet
Dim sh_extract, sh_tocopy As Worksheet
Set sh_extract = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh_tocopy = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim a, b As Long
a = sh_extract.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change column letter if you need to check other column to have last row

    For i = 2 To a
    'If sh_extract.Cells(i, 2).Value = "20040155" or sh_extract.Cells(i, 2).Value = "23358308" Then 
        If sh_extract.Cells(i, 2).Value = "20040155" Then 
            'copy the row
            sh_extract.Rows(i).Copy

            'define the last row of 2nd sheet
            b = sh_tocopy.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Change column letter if you need to check other column to have last row


            'Copy the row
            sh_tocopy.Rows(b).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    sh_extract.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Guicelli Thanks for the help, this seems to make more sense for me, but in the lines "Set sh_extract = wb.Worksheets("ToExtract")" and 
"Set sh_tocopy = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")" I am getting the same runtime error 9 and it says the subscript is out of range

Comment: @JadenEllington could you check the name of your sheets ? I have the same error if I change "sheet2" by random name

Comment: The name of the .xlsx file is ToExtract.xlsx and the sheet is called Sheet1

Comment: OK so on the "Sheet1" you check the condition and "Sheet2" you paste the rows right ?

Comment: So I fixed the error, Sheet1 is where I want to copy the information from Sheet1 onto Sheet2, and I wanted for it to check column B for the code to match the macro for it to paste the whole row onto Sheet2, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok I edited the code with your informations. We check on column B of Sheet2 and we paste on sheet1. Try and  let me know if it's working

Comment: We check column B of Sheet1 and then paste the row onto Sheet2

Comment: It works! Thank you and everyone else for helping me. One last thing, how do I add an "or" command for the values?

Comment: Great, don't forget to validate my answer ;) And I don't anderstand your last thing

Comment: Will do. What I was saying is that if I want to check multiple values in column B, how may I go about doing so. For example, if I want to add "23511308" and "23358308" to the pre-existing value to check.

Comment: Look at the code, I added a comment before the IF condition. Is an example of what you want

Comment: So you can't do " If sh_extract.Cells(i, 2).Value = "20040155" Or "23358308"  Then" ?

Comment: No, you need to repeat the "sh_extract.Cells(i, 2).Value"

Comment: Alright then that's all. Thank you so much for the help on this, as it would have taken me forever.